# Excel VBA do while function to return a value to a cell won't work

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use Excel VBA to generate two numbers. Between one and 11. 
If the numbers are equal, then the second one should re-generate from random. 
If the first one is 8 or 9, then the second one should NOT be 8 or 9. If it is, it should generate from random again.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim thisNum As Integer
    Dim thatNum As Integer
        thatNum = Int((11 * Rnd) + 1)
        thisNum = Int((11 * Rnd) + 1)
        Do While thisNum = thatNum
            thatNum = Int((11 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
            break

        Loop
        Do While (thisNum = 8 Or 9) And (thatNum = 8 Or 9)
            thatNum = Int((11 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
            break

        Loop

        Range("F1").Value = thisNum
        Range("G1").Value = thatNum     
End Sub
```

It crashes, and gives no error. What should I do?

Comment: You say it "crashed and gives no error".  If you insert a breakpoint at the very start of the `Sub` and step through the code in the VBA editor where exactly does it cause Excel to crash?

Comment: Sure, it gives an error. A compile error because `break` doesn't exist. Also, why `(11 - 1 + 1)` instead of `10`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to break the loop because you are in a loop with a condition.

Your condition is wrong on this line :

```
Do While (thisNum = 8 Or 9) And (thatNum = 8 Or 9)
```

You can't compare `thisNum` to two other numbers like that. In your case, you have a infinite loop. You are saying :

```
Do While (thisNum = 8 Or True) And (thatNum = 8 Or True)
```

So it's :

```
Do While True
```

You could use this loop :

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim thisNum As Integer
    Dim thatNum As Integer
    thisNum = Int((11 * Rnd) + 1)

    Do             
        thatNum = Int((11 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
    Loop While (thisNum = thatNum) Or ((thisNum = 8 Or thisNum = 9) And (thatNum = 8 Or thatNum = 9))

    Range("F1").Value = thisNum
    Range("G1").Value = thatNum     
End Sub
```